# isHex() and isOcta() functions

Tags: php, hex, octal

I have Two Functions. **IsOcta** and **isHex**. Can not seem to make isHex work properly.
Issue in isHex() is that it can not omit 'x' notation of the original string *x23*.

Original hex srting can also be *D1CE*. So adding x and then comparing wont do.

**Is there any correct solution to the isHex function. Also is isOcta correct?**

```
function isHex($string){
    (int) $x=hexdec("$string");     // Input must be a String and hexdec returns NUMBER
    $y=dechex($x);          // Must be a Number and dechex returns STRING
    echo "<br />isHex() - Hexa Number Reconverted: ".$y;       

    if($string==$y){
        echo "<br /> Result: Hexa ";
    }else{
        echo "<br /> Result: NOT Hexa";
    }   
    }


function IsOcta($string){
    (int) $x=octdec("$string");     // Input must be a String and octdec returns NUMBER
          $y=decoct($x);            // Must be a Number and decoct returns STRING
    echo "<br />IsOcta() - Octal Number Reconverted: ".$y;          

    if($string==$y){
    echo "<br /> Result: OCTAL";
    }else{
    echo "<br /> Result: NOT OCTAL";
    }

}
```

Here is the Call to the Functions:

```
$hex    =   "x23";      // STRING 
$octa   =   "023";  // STRING 
echo "<br /    Original HEX = $hex | Original Octa = $octa <br /    ";

echo isHex($hex)."<br /    ";   
echo IsOcta($octa);
```

Here is the Result of the Function Call:

```
Original HEX = x23 | Original Octa = 023 

isHex() - Hexa Number Reconverted: 23
Result: NOT Hexa

IsOcta() - Octal Number Reconverted: 23
Result: OCTAL
```

===== COMPLETE ANSWER ====

Thanks Layke for directing to the built in function that tests whether HEXA DECIMAL characters are present in a string or not. Also thanks mario for giving the hint to use ltrim. Both functions were needed to get isHexa or is hexadecimal function to be built.

--- EDITED FUNCTION --

```
// isHEX function

function isHex($strings){

// Does not work as originally suggested by Layke, but thanks for directing to the resource. It does not omit 0x representation of a hexadecimal number. 
/*
foreach ($strings as $testcase) {
     if (ctype_xdigit($testcase)) {
        echo "<br /> $testcase - <strong>TRUE</strong>, Contains only Hex<br />";
    } else {
        echo "<br /> $testcase - False, Is not Hex";

   } 
}
*/

   // This works CORRECTLY
   foreach ($strings as $testcase) {
        if (ctype_xdigit(ltrim($testcase , "0x"))) {
           echo "<br /> $testcase - <strong>TRUE</strong>, Contains only Hex<br />";
       } else {
           echo "<br /> $testcase - False, Is not Hex";

      } 
   }
}

$strings = array('AB10BC99', 'AR1012', 'x23' ,'0x12345678');
isHex($strings); // calling
```

Probably now, is this the fool proof answer to the 'is hexadecimal' function?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### isHexadecimal?

PHP has built in functions for hexadecimal.

See the function here `ctype_xdigit`: https://www.php.net/ctype_xdigit

```
<?php
$strings = array('AB10BC99', 'AR1012', 'ab12bc99');
foreach ($strings as $testcase) {
    if (ctype_xdigit($testcase)) {
        // TRUE : Contains only Hex
    } else {
        // False : Is not Hex
    }
}
```

### isOctal?

And for figuring out if a number is [octal](http://php.net/manual/en/function.octdec.php), you can just flip and flip.

```
function isOctal($x) {
    return decoct(octdec($x)) == $x;
}
```

Comment: thanks. Worked Wonders. Just needed input from Mario to get the proper function. See 
-- EDITED FUNCTION -- above

Comment: partially bad answer. For Octal test '007'.

Comment: This answer is a bit misleading. `isOctal(0123)` => `false`, `isOctal('123')` => `true`. It works with strings as the input, but only tells you whether a string *could* represent an octal, not whether it would be recognized by PHP as an octal.

Answer (score 2):

You can clean up your input string with [`ltrim()`](http://php.net/ltrim) then. Simply add it before doing the first conversion:

```
 $string = ltrim($string, "0x");
```

Will remove both leading zeros (unneeded) and `x` characters.

Comment: thanks, needed your input of ltrim to put final shape to the hint by Layke.

Answer (score 1):

isHexadecimal ::=

```
ctype_xdigit($testString)
```

isOctal ::=

```
preg_match('/^[0-7]+$/', $testString);
```